# shell VAR=$( command ) handling the possible error

Tags: shell, error-handling

When I use VAR=$( command ) to initialize a variable how I can handle the possible return of error exit code from the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if var=$(command)
then : OK - it worked
else : Oops - it failed
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
var=$(command 2>/dev/null)
```

It is better to use lowercase variables in shell scripts to avoid conflicts with reserved variables.

Comment: My question is if the command fail, how I to make my script to stop or handle it in some other way.

Comment: ok I think answer from @JonathanLeffler might work for you in that case.